# css3 animation keep reverting to original state

Tags: css, animation

Playing around with CSS 3 animations but for some reasons, all animations return to their original state after execution.

In this case I'd like the image to remain at `scale(1)` after animation and my text to oly appear after img animation but stay afterward.

```
.expanding-spinning {
   -webkit-transform: scale(.4);
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
   animation-duration: 500ms;
}

.expanding-spinning {
  -webkit-animation: spin2 1.4s ease-in-out alternate;
  animation: spin2 1.4s ease-in-out alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(.4);}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);}
}
@-keyframes spin2 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) scale(.4);}
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display:none; 
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    display: block; 
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.slogan {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInFromNone;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
```

[Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/WHFmB/1)

Comment: your animation doesn't work at all!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to add the rule `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to your animations.

Also, regarding the text animation: Animate the `visibility` property instead of `display` property

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/WHFmB/6/)**

```
.expanding-spinning {
  -webkit-animation: spin2 1.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: spin2 1.4s linear normal;
  -o-animation: spin2 1.4s linear;
  -ms-animation: spin2 1.4s linear;
  animation: spin2 1.4s ease-in-out alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* <--- */
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {
        visibility:hidden; 
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        visibility: visible; 
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.slogan {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInFromNone;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3.4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* <--- */
}
```

See [this article](http://www.css3files.com/animation/) for a nice explanation of all the animation properties

> The fill mode. If set to forwards, the last keyframe remains at the
> end of the animation,

(from above link)